# Web apps through D-Link DFL-860e NetDefend Firewall

Tags: nat

I have a Windows webserver which resides inside a LAN 172.20.10.0/24. I want my webserver to serve IIS pages over the internet behind a D-Link DFL-860e NetDefend Firewall, through my company's public IP address and a web browser.

The way it works now (see Steps done below), **I can reach my webserver** through my public IP address. However, when I try to use a web app like *[public-ip/app_name]*, there's no response.

Product manual has been of great help so far, but I haven't able to figure out this bit.

Steps done so far:

- Configured a SAT rule like this:

  - Interface: any as Source, wan1 as Destination.
  - Network: all-nets as Source, my_public_ip as Destination
  - Service is http-in
- Added a NAT rule with the same source and destination interfaces and networks and same service.

I managed to make it work through a simple Windows Server 2003 Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) configuration, but now we need to replace said server with this new Firewall.

Connection from my LAN devices to the Internet works fine.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **RTFM**.
[DFL 860E User Manual](http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Business_Products/DFL/DFL%20860E/Manual/DFL%20860E_User%20Manual_EN_US.pdf) Chapter 7 "Address Translation".

My specific problem is addressed on Section 7.4.1. I need to allow my internal server to use my router's IP when replying to a remote device, we need to define a NAT rule for this. Then, we also need to Allow traffic to go from my lan or DMZ into the internet, this means also a new IP rule.

In my case, configuration should add **three IP rules** like this:

- SAT RULE:

  - Source: any as Interface, all-nets as Network
  - Destination: core as Interface, wan1_ip as Network (public IP, assigned to this router)
  - Service is http-in in my case
  - Webserver local IP goes on the SAT tab.
- NAT RULE

  - Source: lan as Interface, lan-net as Network (or DMZ if you're using one, which you should)
  - Destination: any as Interface, all-nets as Network.
  - Service can either be "all_services", or http_in in my case according to the manual. I chose the later.
- ALLOW RULE

  - Source: any as Interface, all-nets as Network.
  - Destination: core as Interface, wan1_ip as Network.
  - Service is again, http-in for my case

Hope this helps somebody.

Cheers.